# How to use getStaticProps in _app.js for showing data fetched from api in every pages in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

To be specific I am showing data on the navbar from the API endpoint. And I want to use getStaticProps to get those data on all the pages. But the problem is I need to do getStaticProps on all the pages.

Can we do something like this and get data on all the pages as props?

```js
//pages/_app.js
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps, navs }) {
  return (
    <>
      <Component {...pageProps} navs={navs} />
    </>
  );
}
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const res = await api.get("/api/v1/navs");
  const navs = res.data;
  return {
    props: {
      navs,
    },
    // revalidate: 60, // In seconds
  };
}

export default MyApp;
```

What could be the alternative way of doing this? Is there a way to manage a global state, so that it is used by all the pages? I don't think we can use Context API to provide data to all the pages too.

Comment: Unfortunately, Next's lifecycle methods aren't available in `_app.js`. The alternative would be to use client side requests with a Redux solution from within the _app.js file (see [Next Redux example](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-redux)). On that note, your example is turning `navs` into a boolean when it's assigned as a prop to `Component` (should be `navs={navs}`).

Comment: I actually wanted the navs to be statically rendered, so client-side request and rendering is not the option I am searching using Nextjs. 
Yeah, I got your point on passing props. I just missed that but still thanks for reminding.

Comment: Discussion here: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/10949

Answer (score 27):

### Problem

NextJS doesn't currently support lifecycle methods in `_app.js`.

### Solution

Since the above isn't supported yet, you'll want to create a reusable `getStaticProps` function and export it from **all pages**. Unfortunately, this does mean some WET code; however, you can reduce some boilerplate by creating a [HOC](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) which wraps the page and also exports a getStaticProps function.

#### Alternatives

You can use `getInitialProps` within the `_app.js` file. Unfortunately, this disables automatic static optimization **across the entire application**.

#### Demo

[image: Edit Static Optimized List]

#### Code

**components/Navigation**

```
import * as React from "react";
import Link from "next/link";
import { nav, navItem } from "./Navigation.module.css";

const Navigation = () => (
  <div className={nav}>
    {[
      { title: "Home", url: "/" },
      { title: "About", url: "/about" },
      { title: "Help", url: "/help" }
    ].map(({ title, url }) => (
      <div className={navItem} key={title}>
        <Link href={url}>
          {/* eslint-disable-next-line jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid */}
          <a>{title}</a>
        </Link>
      </div>
    ))}
  </div>
);

export default Navigation;
```

**components/UsersList**

```
import * as React from "react";
import isEmpty from "lodash.isempty";
import { noUsers, title, userList, user } from "./UsersList.module.css";

const UsersList = ({ error, users, retrieved }) =>
  !retrieved ? (
    <p>Loading...</p>
  ) : !isEmpty(users) ? (
    <div className={userList}>
      <h1 className={title}>Statically Optimized User List</h1>
      {users.map(({ name }) => (
        <div className={user} key={name}>
          {name}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  ) : (
    <div className={noUsers}>{error || "Failed to load users list"}</div>
  );

export default UsersList;
```

**containers/withUsersList**

```
import * as React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import UsersList from "../../components/UsersList";

/**
 * A HOC that wraps a page and adds the UserList component to it.
 *
 * @function withUsersList
 * @param Component - a React component (page)
 * @returns {ReactElement}
 * @example withUsersList(Component)
 */
const withUsersList = (Component) => {
  const wrappedComponent = (props) => (
    <>
      <UsersList {...props} />
      <Component {...props} />
    </>
  );

  return wrappedComponent;
};

export const getStaticProps = async () => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");

    return {
      props: {
        retrieved: true,
        users: res.data,
        error: ""
      }
    };
  } catch (error) {
    return {
      props: {
        retrieved: true,
        users: [],
        error: error.toString()
      }
    };
  }
};

export default withUsersList;
```

**pages/_app.js**

```
import * as React from "react";
import Navigation from "../components/Navigation";

const App = ({ Component, pageProps }) => (
  <>
    <Navigation />
    <Component {...pageProps} />
  </>
);

export default App;
```

**pages/about**

```
import withUsersList, { getStaticProps } from "../containers/withUsersList";

const AboutPage = () => <div>About Us.</div>;

export { getStaticProps };

export default withUsersList(AboutPage);
```

**pages/help**

```
import withUsersList, { getStaticProps } from "../containers/withUsersList";

const HelpPage = () => <div>Find Help Here.</div>;

export { getStaticProps };

export default withUsersList(HelpPage);
```

**pages/index**

```
import withUsersList, { getStaticProps } from "../containers/withUsersList";

const IndexPage = () => <div>Hello World.</div>;

export { getStaticProps };

export default withUsersList(IndexPage);
```

Comment: Using `getInitialProps` in `_app.js` doesn't actually disable SSG across the entire application (build a Next.js app and see for yourself).

Comment: It'll disable **automatic static optimization**, not static pages: [source](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/automatic-static-optimization#caveats)

Comment: but what if I want to use getServerSideProps in index page insted of export { getStaticProps } how to resolve this issue ?

Comment: No different than the above, but use `getServerSideProps` instead. The only difference will be that it retrieves data during runtime instead of at buildtime.

Comment: I've tried this but getStaticProps() doesn't even initialise