# API Call on _app.tsx file in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am making an application which needs a `Sidebar` and the data of sidebar is getting fetched from an API.

Now, Sidebar is a component I can't call `getStaticProps` method inside this component.And I am putting this sidebar inside the _app.tsx file so that it can be open and close throughout the application(using context api).

Now I want to call an API and make sure data is available to my `Sidebar` component

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use getStaticProps in \_app.js for showing data fetched from api in every pages in Next.js](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67642216/11613622), [getStaticProps on _app](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/10949)

Comment: No, this need wrapping of all my components which is not feasible for large scale applications.