# Is there a way to populate MobX storage during the initial loading?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, mobx

I'm building a simple Next.js website that has many components nested many levels deep though all of them literally use the same data (article names, project names, faq cards data and stuff like that).

1. According to [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app#caveats) there is no way i can `getStaticProps()` once in _app.tsx. My only option in this case is experimental `/app` folder which i do not want to use
2. I can't just externalize some custom `getCommonStaticProps()` and use it in every single time because i need to pass the same props not only to pages but to components also.
3. I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67640024/how-to-use-getstaticprops-in-app-js-for-showing-data-fetched-from-api-in-every) post on similar issue which proposes hacky solution in my opinion

My question is: is there some way to put data into MobX storage for an entire application during the initial loading so that all nested pages and components see this data without passing props to components and putting `getStaticProps()` on every single page?

Example structure

```
PageLayout.tsx (same props) --> _app.tsx --> index.tsx (same props)
```

_app.tsx

```
export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <>
      <PageLayout>// needs prop1, prop1
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </PageLayout>
    </>
  )
};
```

index.tsx

```
export const getStaticProps = async () => {
  ...
  return {
    props {
      prop1,
      prop2
    }
  }
}
const Home: NextPage<staticProps> = ({prop1, prop2}) => {
  return (
    <>
      <MyComponent />
      <AnotherComponent data={prop1} />// needs prop1
      <AnotherComponent data={prop2} />// needs prop2
    </>
  )
}

export default Home;
```

PageLayout.tsx (component)

```
interface Props {
    children: React.ReactNode
}

const PageLayout: NextPage<Props> = ({children}) => {
  return (
    <main>
      <Menu />
        <div>
          {children}
        </div>
      <Footer />// needs prop1, prop2
    </main>
  );
}

export default PageLayout;
```

Answer (score 1):

If we only talk about `/pages` ([there is also newer](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/data-fetching/fundamentals) `/app` approach for Next.js 13+, but it's not recommended for production at this moment, it might be unstable), then the only way to fetch something for all the routes at once is to use `getInitialProps` in your custom `_app` component. The major caveat is that it disables [Automatic Static Optimization](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/automatic-static-optimization), so your pages will no longer be statically generated as if you used `getStaticProps`. `getStaticProps` is not available in `_app`.

If you want to preserve static generation then you must use `getStaticProps`. My advice would be to create some sort of common method that you could reuse between pages, then you only need to reexport it from the page, like so:

```
// Do that in every page where you need the data, e.g. /pages/index.js
import { getCommonStaticProps } from '/some-file'

export const getStaticProps = getCommonStaticProps;

// Your page component where you render things and etc
const PageComponent = () => { ... }

export default PageComponent
```

The good news is that I think you can initialize your store only once in the `_app` file, because you get the props from `getStaticProps` there too:

```
// _app.js file
const CustomApp = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
  // You probably want to create it here in a similar way
  const [store] = useState(() => new Store(pageProps))

  // And then use your store provider like you probably already do 
  return (
    <StoreContext.Provider value={store}>
      ...
    </StoreContext.Provider>
  )
}

export default CustomApp
```

[More info about custom app](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app)

And `StoreContext` will look like that:

```
export const StoreContext = React.createContext()

// This is the hook that you can use in your component that needs the store
export const useStore = () => React.useContext(StoreContext)
```

In the component you just use the hook:

```
// Don't forget to wrap it with MobX `observer` HOC
const MyComponentThatNeedsStore = observer(() => {
  const store = useStore()

  // ...
})
```

Comment: I am already familiar with Context, the way it wraps things and how to consume it in nested components which makes your solution look familiar but i still do not understand a few things.

1. I am not sure i understand what `<StoreProvider>` is. 
  
2. If i got it right, to make things work i get the data with `getStaticProps` inside _app right before `const CustomApp = ...` then wrap everything with a store the way you described 3. If i do exactly the way you described then how do i access data  in nested components ? Do i need to consume/import anything or just say `store.whatever`?

Comment: @GeorgyMartynovich I've expanded my answer a little bit to give you more details. Let me know if something is not clear :)

Comment: I've updated my question a little more so you get a better idea of what my project really looks like. If there actually is a way to use `getStaticProps` in `_app.js` then create a store there to make the data available to all children, then could you please explain this one again step by step file by file. Do i need to create a store in `_app.tsx` ? Do i create context in a separate file ? Where do i put the Hook to consume a context ? How is MobX store and context related ? Are they ? If it is too much then any links and usefull resources would be good. Thanks for you patience!